# Dropdown in the cell is hidden and does not show properly

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to use a dropdown list in the cell using the template.
When i try to open the dropdown it does not overflow.It is hidden.

[image]

Can you please let me know how to fix this.
I modified the original plunker to create a dropdown.

Here is the link to the plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/94uZfo02rXBOmGoQn91J?p=preview

If I use  cellClass: 'overflow' will that be ok.

```
 .overflow {
     overflow:visible;
 }
```

modified plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/qp5ujopzr0bvq73fPkZL?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is from this class, either change it to visible or remove the overflow totally

```
.ui-grid-cell {
    /* overflow: hidden;
```

or append this to your main.css

```
.ui-grid-cell {
    overflow: visible;
```

and *voila*